# how to make blaze-layout render each template as static in div, expanding it

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, meteor-blaze

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooAgw.png)I'm using Meteor with blaze-layout
and have structure like this

```
<div id="list">
{{#each somedata}}
  {{> Template_for_this_data}}
{{/each}}
</div>
<footer>here is footer</footer>
```

And when there is lot of "somedata"s all templates works like absolute elements. they cover footer, not expanding the parent div. They are not childrens of body or html.

Comment: This sounds like you're having a CSS issue.  Have you inspected the elements in the DOM to see if they are being generated in the right place as far as the HTML is concerned?  To me, this sounds like a styling problem.

Comment: How many is "a lot of"? 100, 10,000? 1,000,000?

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Sure, Check it out now. It's at start of my question

Comment: This definitely seems related to your CSS, and not directly related to Blaze template rendering. More information would be necessary to answer the question.